# Uncaught Error: WebGL unsupported in this browser

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Hi I'm trying to use PixiJS to render things in my browser but I keep getting a very annoying error:

```
Uncaught Error: WebGL unsupported in this browser, use "pixi.js-legacy" for fallback canvas2d support.
```

WebGL is supported by my browser tho : https://i.gyazo.com/8e55f75c74dd738c55d646bce3cdc294.png

Here's my very simple js:

```
let app = new PIXI.Application({width: 800, height: 800});
document.body.appendChild(app);
```

And my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<script src="pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="chess.js"></script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed it by using legacy version but I would really like to know how to fix it with the current version.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I think you need to update pixi.js setting as following [ref1](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/7070) [ref2](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.settings.html#FAIL_IF_MAJOR_PERFORMANCE_CAVEAT):

```js
PIXI.settings.FAIL_IF_MAJOR_PERFORMANCE_CAVEAT = false;
```

Please note, that browsers are now supporting low performance by default. so it may limit the current page from rendering 3d that may require high performance. you could follow up on [failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1678652) which is need to be passed in the context or you could force browser settings as following:

so for

#### Firefox

1. Go to about:config, search for **webgl.disabled**, ensure that its value is **false**.
2. Go to about:config, search for **webgl.force-enabled**, set it to **true**.
3. Go to about:config, search for **layers.acceleration.force-enabled**, set it to **true**.
4. restart your firefox.

I am not really sure about chrome configurations.

Comment: For Chrome configurations, you can check them at `chrome://gpu`.  You're looking for WebGL / WebGL2.  If Hardware Acceleration is off (or software only), it can be toggled on/off under `Settings > Advanced > System > Use Hardware Acceleration`.  One caveat is that if you're doing this in a VM, Chrome will be limited to whether or not you've enabled 3D Acceleration on the VM.